# Javascript: Why is my code alerting to nothing?

Tags: javascript, math, alert

I've written the following:

```
var pages=["[www.facebook.com] Facebook is cool. ","[www.bbc.co.uk] British broadcasting corporation. "];

function findScoreC2(s){ 
  var scores=[];
  var percentageScores=[];
  var contentsArray=[];
  s=s.toLowerCase();
  for(i=0;i<pages.length; i++){
    contentsArray=pages[i].substring(pages[i].indexOf("]")+1,pages[i].lastIndexOf(" "));
    var lowerCaseContents=(pages[i].substring(pages[i].indexOf("]")+1,pages[i].lastIndexOf(" "))).toLowerCase();
    scores[i] =(lowerCaseContents.split(s)).length-1
  };

  percentageScores=(scores[i] / contentsArray[i].length) * 100;
  var finalArray=[];

  for(i=0;i<percentageScores.length;i++){
    finalArray.push("{score:"+percentageScores[i]+",index:"+i+"}")
  };
  alert(finalArray);
}


findScoreC2("facebook");
```

however, `alert(finalArray)` alerts to nothing (ie an alert box comes up but it says nothing) when it should alert `"{score:33,index:0},{score:0,index:1}"`.

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this might be?

Thanks very much

Comment: I can't see the code properly, maybe you need to edit your question

Comment: Even I couldn't see it when I wasn't logged in. After logging in, I was able to. I don't know why.. but for some reason that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You set `percentageScores` to a number. You then try to iterate  up to its `length` property, which gives you `undefined` when you do `percentageScores.length`, so the for loop never iterates. You then alert with an empty array, whose `toString` produces the empty string.

You probably want this:

```
for(i=0;i<pages.length; i++){
    contentsArray=pages[i].substring(pages[i].indexOf("]")+1,pages[i].lastIndexOf(" "));
    var lowerCaseContents=(pages[i].substring(pages[i].indexOf("]")+1,pages[i].lastIndexOf(" "))).toLowerCase();
    scores[i] =(lowerCaseContents.split(s)).length-1
    percentageScores[i]=(scores[i] / contentsArray[i].length) * 100;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just given that a try as I realised at roughly the same time you wrote back that I the percentageScores line was outside the for-loop, so i changed the code to include it, and in the for-loop at the end, changed it to iterate up to scores.length (rather than percentage scores). Now, it alerts to "{score:undefined, index:0},{score:undefined, index:1}" but I can't see what the problem is now

Comment: did you add the [i] to the percentageScores when indexing into it?

Comment: I didn't, but having just read your reply and done so, it works! well almost. now i'm getting "{score:100,index:0}" which would seem to indicate that it thinks the value of contentsArray[0] is 1, when it's actually 3 ("Facebook is cool.")?

Thanks very much for all your help, I appreciate it.